# Static Website Membership Options: Any alternatives (open source or paid) to MemberSpace?

Tags: web-apps, web-development, web, web-services, static-site-generator

I've come across an interesting and robust membership management system for static websites called MemberSpace.com. Unfortunately I'm not thrilled with its content gating options:
[Is MemberSpace secure?](https://help.memberspace.com/article/70-is-memberspace-secure)

Their [case studies](https://www.memberspace.com/#case-studies) are also impressive.

Are there any other similar solutions that are perhaps server based for content that run on top of your own web server while still allowing static content upload and gating?  Are there any other competitors to this service in this space?

Open source or commercial options are both welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Userbase is a great open source solution: https://userbase.com/

This post has a bunch of other options that look viable: https://medium.com/visualdevspace/9-awesome-tools-you-can-use-to-build-membership-sites-e173e912c8a7

Headless CMSs like Ghost might offer something similar: https://ghost.org/vs/memberful/